# Python cannot see global variable

Tags: python

Although i am specyfing a variable as `global` inside a function like this:

```
def SECdownload(year, month):
    import os
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    root = None
    feedFile = None
    feedData = None
    good_read = False
    itemIndex = 0
    edgarFilingsFeed = 'http://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/monthly/xbrlrss-' + str(year) + '-' + str(month).zfill(2) + '.xml'
    return edgarFilingsFeed
    #print( edgarFilingsFeed ) #from the slides
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) )
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )
    global target_dir
    target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'
```

And then i import the function  and then run it in the Python UI (Windows) like this:

```
>>> from df import SECdownload
>>> SECdownload(2012,4)
```

Why when i type the variable `target_dir` in the Shell i get:

```
>>> target_dir
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    target_dir

NameError: name 'target_dir' is not defined
```

How is this possible **when i clearly state** inside the function that the `variable` is `global` ?

Comment: i will put the line `global target_dir` out of the function declaration... maybe that is the problem

Comment: By using return you are excluding everything else from executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions work in the context in which they were created. That is, any globals they work with are local to the module that the function was created in.

For instance:

m.py:

```
def a(val):
    global x
    x = val
```

main.py

```
from m import a
a(10)
import m
print(m.x)
```

produces `10`

Answer (score 1):

Your code dealing with the global variable is unreachable because of this line:

```
return edgarFilingsFeed
```

Comment: ohhh but isn't the line `target_dir = "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) + '/'` being read anyway? Otherwise how it creates the directory when i run the module? I must admit though that this must be the problem

Comment: I doubt that it's creating a directory with the code that you have shown us.

Comment: Ohhh i get it! It only goes there is the directory is entirely missing (untested)

Comment: well doesnt these lines make a directory: `if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) )
    if not os.path.exists( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) ):
        os.makedirs( "sec/" + str(year) + '/' + str(month).zfill(2) )`?

Comment: And all of those lines are unreachable because of the return statement. So they will never execute. So the code you have presented us (as a whole) will not create directories.

Comment: OHhhhhhhh i understand thank you!!!! `return` immediately pulls the plug right? prease verify if yes :P